# ArcGIS Raster to Float tool ends up with different coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am exporting a raster within a geodatabase to a flt file using Raster to Float tool in ArcGIS 10.7

The raster had an XY coordinate system of GDA 1994 **MGA** Zone 56.

When I checked the coordinate system of the Float file, it's GDA 1994 **UTM** Zone 56**S**.

Can someone explain why this is happening? I checked under "environment" to set the coordinate system to be "Same as Input" but this still happened.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the data so others can see if they can replicate the issue. The obvious culprit is the environment setting but you seemed to have checked that?

Comment: The data is privileged and am likely not allowed to put it online unfortunately. I asked this question mostly thinking someone will tell me they're the same as they have the same "properties" (looking at the linear unit, angular unit, false easting, datum etc). They were all the same except for how it's called.